# Downloading images using a thread pool, with exception handling

Tags: python, multithreading, error-handling, http

I'm currently using a broad Exception handler in my code and I would like to remove this broad exception. Which exceptions should I handle? Are these exceptions generated in my function "func" or which ones? I would like to list them.

Using [this](http://masnun.com/2016/03/29/python-a-quick-introduction-to-the-concurrent-futures-module.html) page as reference:

```
# Retrieve a single page and report the url and contents
def load_url(url, timeout):
    if not url:
       raise ValueError('Invalid URL')
    with urllib.request.urlopen(url, timeout=timeout) as conn:
        return conn.read()    

with futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=_MAX_WORKERS) as executor:
        # Start the load operations and mark each future with its URL            
        future_to_url = {
              executor.submit(load_url, _EXECUTOR_TIMEOUT): image
              for image in image_list
        }
        for future in futures.as_completed(future_to_url):
          image = future_to_url[future]
          try:
            images.append((image.master_id, future.result()))
          except Exception as exc: 
            logging.exception('%r Generated an exception: %s', image.url, exc)
```

Comment: How can we possibly answer this if you don't show us the code for `func`?

Comment: Hi Gareth, I just edited the original post, thanks for replying

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The docs for `urllib.request.urlopen` suggest that `HTTPError` & `URLError` will typically be raised, in addition to your `ValueError`. Other rare ones are possible so sticking with `Exception`, as you have it, seems reasonable.